# How do I show a field based on the selection of another field

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have a form field, when I select a car, I want to get the type of car or the result of the model.

```
    $this->crud->addField([
            'name'  => 'car_id',
            'label' => 'Car',
            'type'  => 'select2_from_ajax',
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'model' => Car::class,
            'data_source' => url('admin/api/cars'),
            'placeholder' => 'Search and select a car',
            'minimum_input_length' => 2,
        ]);
```

And how do I use the result to determine which other fields to show in the form?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in Backpack v5 using the included [CrudField JS Library](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-fields-javascript-api). To hide/show other fields depending on `card_id`, you should:

**Step 1.** In your `setupCreateOperation()` and/or `setupUpdateOperation()` load a new JS file:

```php
Widget::add()->type('script')->content('assets/js/admin/forms/product.js');
```

**Step 2.** Create that JS file. Inside it, you can now easily select and get the value of Backpack fields. To show/hide other fields depending on `car_id`:

```js
crud.field('car_id').onChange(function(field) {
  // eg. show "car_model" if "car_id" is 1
  crud.field('car_model').show(field.value == 1); 
}).change();
```

For more things you can do with the CrudField JS Library, check out [its docs](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-fields-javascript-api#syntax-1).